# Array.IndexOf ,. index our of range execption

Tags: c#, arrays

I am using,

```
if(Array.IndexOf(myArray, otherArray[i+1]) > -1);
```

to see if a vaulue on otherArray is in myArray. I expected either a value of -1 if the value is not in the array or the index location if it was. How ever I am getting an  IndexOutOFRange exception .

Could anyone point me in the right direction.

ADDED. Hi Jacob, thats what i thought at first, that i+1 was an out of the range of otherArray  but its not. Here is the relevent bits of code,

```
                // Add values to Level list

                    levels.Add(r3);
                    levels.Add(r2);
                    levels.Add(r1);
                    levels.Add(pp);
                    levels.Add(s1);
                    levels.Add(s2);
                    levels.Add(s3);


                    if((r3-r2) > 50*TickSize)
                        {
                        levels.Add((r2+(r3-r2)/3));
                        levels.Add((r2+(r3-r2)*2/3));
                        }
                    else if((r3-r2) > psb)
                        levels.Add((r2+(r3-r2)/2));

                    if((r2-r1) > 50*TickSize)
                        {
                        levels.Add((r1+(r2-r1)/3));
                        levels.Add((r1+(r2-r1)*2/3));
                        }
                    else if((r2-r1) > psb)
                        levels.Add((r1+(r2-r1)/2));

                    if((r1-pp) > 50*TickSize)
                        {
                        levels.Add((pp+(r1-pp)/3));
                        levels.Add((pp+(r1-pp)*2/3));
                        }
                    else if((r1-pp) > psb)
                        levels.Add((pp+(r1-pp)/2));

                    if((pp-s1) > 50*TickSize)
                        {
                        levels.Add((s1+(pp-s1)/3));
                        levels.Add((s1+(pp-s1)*2/3));
                        }
                    else if((pp-s1) > psb)
                        levels.Add((s1+(pp-s1)/2));

                    if((s1-s2) > 50*TickSize)
                        {
                        levels.Add((s2+(s1-s2)/3));
                        levels.Add((s2+(s1-s2)*2/3));
                        }
                    else if((s1-r2) > psb)
                        levels.Add((s2+(s1-s2)/2));

                    if((s2-s3) > 50*TickSize)
                        {
                        levels.Add((s3+(s2-s3)/3));
                        levels.Add((s3+(s2-s3)*2/3));
                        }
                    else if((s2-s3) > psb)
                        levels.Add((s3+(s2-s3)/2));




            }


                        pivots[6] = r3; // Puts Pivots  into array
                        pivots[5] = r2;
                        pivots[4] = r1;
                        pivots[3] = pp;
                        pivots[2] = s1;
                        pivots[1] = s2;
                        pivots[0] = s3;
                        pivots[7] = Closes[mBIP][0];


levels.Add (High[0]);
double[] lev = levels.ToArray();
Array.Sort (lev);

i = Array.BinarySearch(lev,High[0]); //finds the Array index of current High


if(High[0] >= r3 && Close[0] > lev[i-1] && pStop.StopPrice < Math.Max(lev[i-1],High[0]-10*TickSize))
{
pStop = ExitLongStop(0, true,Position.Quantity, Math.Max(lev[i-1], High[0]-10*TickSize), "Stop of Long", "pEntry");
target = Math.Max(High[0]+1*TickSize, r3+10*TickSize );
fillBar = CurrentBar;

                            }
else if(High[0] >= lev[i+1]-(Math.Max(2*TickSize,(lev[i+1] - pivots[Array.IndexOf(pivots, lev[i+1])-1])*0.1)) && Array.IndexOf(pivots, lev[i+1]) > -1 && Close[0] > lev[i-1] && pStop.StopPrice < lev[i-1]) // Checks to see if High[] is within 2 ticks of Major Pivot or 10% of Major pivot range
                            {
                                pStop = ExitLongStop(0, true,Position.Quantity, lev[i-1], "Stop of Long", "pEntry");
                                target = lev[i+2];
                                fillBar = CurrentBar;
                            }
```

I hope this is all the relevant code.

Comment: might be your otherArray[i+1] is throwing this exception,gave more details by posting code

Comment: There is no `Array.IndexOf` function in *JavaScript*. Are you sure this is the actual programming language?

Comment: @aelor: How do *you* know the programming language? It might as well be [tag:Java] or whatever. Let the OP [edit] his question himself.

Comment: @Bergi yes true I just added it cause this is possible in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you get the `IndexOutOfRangeException` at `otherArray[i+1]` because the size of `otherArray` is equal or smaller than `i`. Then you should chek it:

```
if(otherArray.Length > i+1 && Array.IndexOf(myArray, otherArray[i+1]) != -1)
{
    // ...
}
```

Also:

> I expected either a value of -1 if the value is not in the array

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

Return Value

> The index of the first occurrence of value within the entire array, if
>   found; **otherwise, the lower bound of the array minus 1**.

So you don't get always -1 if the object is not in the array.

> Since most arrays will have a lower bound of zero, this method would
>   generally return –1 when value is not found. **In the rare case that the
>   lower bound of the array is equal to Int32.MinValue and value is not
>   found, this method returns Int32.MaxValue, which is
>   System.Int32.MinValue - 1**.

You can create arrays with a lower bound other than 0 with [`Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Why don't you use `Enumerable.Contains` which increases also readability:

```
if(myArray.Contains(otherArray.ElementAtOrDefault(i+1)))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i can think of is otherArray[i+1] does not exsist, do you definitely have your indexing correct? Try debugging it and putting otherArray[x], x being something you know exsists, if that works then you know the problem is elsewhere.